# listing items with ngFor and ngIf at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create cards with ngFor but I also want to use ngIf. So if array is empty a card must shown which says "No title!" and if array contains some values then cards must show the values of array.

```
<mat-card class="asd cardPardding" *ngFor="let title of titles">
  <p>
  {{title}}
  </p>
</mat-card>
```

But with this code it lists the array items, if I include ngIf to

then ngFor disable card item so it doesn't make sense.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Angular containers and templates :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="titles?.length; else noTitle">
  <mat-card class="asd cardPardding" *ngFor="let title of titles">
    <p>
    {{title}}
    </p>
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noTitle>
  <mat-card class="asd cardPardding">
    <p>
    No title !
    </p>
</mat-card>
</ng-template>
```